# If statement not covered in Code Coverage in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

When I use Jasmine marbles for unit testing for if condition those specific blocks don't cover in code coverage report.

Is there a way to unit test if blocks so that they would be covered in code coverage report?

below is the code ts file :

```js
onSubscribe(): void {
  this.menuData$.subscribe((menuValue): void => {
    this.menuList = MenuUtils.menuformt(menuValue, this.data);
    this.menuList && this.menuList.map((element: MenuList) => {
      if (this.router.url.includes(element.url)) {
        element.active = true;
      } else {
        element.active = false;
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Below is the unit testing code:

```js
const menuList: MenuList[] = [{
  menu_name: 'MENU_LIST.NEW_BOOKING',
  class: '',
  url: 'services',
  is_hosted: true,
  is_shown_login: true,
  showOnCondition: 'isHostedWithLogin',
  is_hide_login: true,
  hidden: false,
  displayOrder: 1,
  options: null,
  active: false,
}, ];

describe('onSubscribe', (): void => {
  it('should call onSubscribe', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onSubscribe').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubscribe();
    expect(component.onSubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  const menu: MenuList = menuList[0];
  const menuListdata: MenuList[] = menuList;
  it('should includes url', fakeAsync(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    const mockUrlTree = router.parseUrl('/booking/_m/sites/56793/services');
    router.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubscribe();
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      expect(router.url).toContain(element.url)
    });
  }));
  it('should active be true', fakeAsync(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    const mockUrlTree = router.parseUrl('/booking/_m/sites/56793/services');
    router.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubscribe();
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      if (expect(router.url).toContain(element.url)) {
        expect(element.active).toBe(true);
      }
    });
  }));
  it('should active be true', fakeAsync(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    const mockUrlTree = router.parseUrl('/booking/_m/sites/56793/login');
    router.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubscribe();
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      if (expect(router.url).not.toContain(element.url)) {
        expect(element.active).toBe(false);
      }
    })
  }));
});
```

Not sure whether the coding style for unit testing is correct or not let me know if needed any improvement.

from above ts file from if block code is not covered not sure where i am going

this is case i am trying to write it
Thanks.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/ (that site has a complete testing guide, I use it as reference)

Comment: @DanielPerales here i am not using routing i am simply checking the url includes the string or not

Comment: Yes, but the url is in the router object.

Comment: router.navigate(["/services"]).then(() => {
          expect(location.path()).toBe("/" + element.url);
          expect(router.url).toContain(element.url)

        });

@DanielPerales something like above i have tried

Comment: I suggest you to isolate the test and debug. 1. Change the spec file "describe" for "fdescribe" or "it" for "fit" so only this group of tests or one particular test is executed to focus on the problem, 2. launch tests with source maps active (see angular.json configuration), and when the test browser opens search for the component file to be tested in Chrome Dev Tools (F12 - Sources - ctrl+p) and put a breakpoint. With this you will be able to debug the component code and see why it's not passing by that line of code. Check the variables you setup in the test case also. Hope that helps!